# In R tcltk, how to check whether a widget exists and replace it if it does?

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm working on a tcltk interface in R that creates a set of drop down combo boxes based on the fields in whichever dataset is loaded by the user. Right now I have a button ("getbox") to press after loading the data that reads the data then creates a combo box with an option for each field. I'd like to be able to re-create the combo box each time I press the button instead of adding a new combo box. Here is an example of what I have:

```
tt <- tktoplevel()
comboframe <- tkframe(tt)

   getbox <- tkbutton(tt, text = "Create Combo Box", command = function() {
        fields <- names(mtcars)
        cbox <- tkwidget(comboframe, "ComboBox", editable = FALSE, values = fields)
        tkgrid(cbox) 
        })

   tkgrid(getbox)
   tkgrid(comboframe)
```

I tried adding an if statement in the getbox command function, but couldn't get it to work.

```
if (exists(comboframe)) {
    tkdestroy(comboframe)
}  # then create combobox ...
```

Any thoughts on how to replace the combo box instead of adding a new one? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know R, but why are you checking if the frame `comboframe` exists? Why not `if (exists(cbox)) {tkdestroy(cbox)}` between creating the `fields` and creating the `cbox`?

Comment: I was checking for the frame instead of the combo box because I actually have six combo boxes in the real script and 'm trying to do the same thing also with a second button that creates one check box for each field in the dataset - the single combo box was a simpler example. I need the function to delete all the check boxes and all the combo boxes before re-creating them each time the button is pressed. I thought it would be simpler to delete the frame and thereby delete all the combo/check boxes included in the frame than to check for each box and delete it.

Comment: ... but even the 'if (exists(cbox)) {tkdestroy(cbox)}' doesn't work - it gives the same error (Error in exists(cbox) : object 'cbox' not found)

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I don't think I can help you more than that :(

Comment: I know Tcl/Tk, not R, but "if (exists(cbox))" should NOT be throwing an error if cbox doesn't exist - that's the entire purpose of the construct.  Look for syntax issues in that area.  (Mis-spell?  missing punctuation?)

Comment: Figured it out! It just wasn't finding the frame. Here is the corrected code:  `tt <- tktoplevel()


   getbox <- tkbutton(tt, text = "Create Combo Box", command = function() {
 if (exists('comboframe')) {
     tkdestroy(comboframe)
 } 
 comboframe <<- tkframe(tt)
        fields <- names(mtcars)
        cbox <- tkwidget(comboframe, "ComboBox", editable = FALSE, values = fields)
        tkgrid(cbox) 
    tkgrid(comboframe)
        })

   tkgrid(getbox)`